# Is there believed to be sharp boundary between Jupiter's liquid and metallic hydrogen layers and is there much convection and flow between them?

Tags: planetary-science, jupiter, hydrogen

If it's not known, is it reasonable to assume that some Jupiter-like exoplanets might have well separated liquid and metallic hydrogen layers given moderately different temperature and mass?

[image: 2014 Diagram of Jupiter]
**Author:** [Kelvinsong](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Kelvin13)

Comment: How should anybody know? We are not able to send a probe into Jupiter. We can not set hydrogen under the same pressure in a lab. We may only use theoretical calculations or numerical simulations but we can not compare the results with measurements from Jupiter.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question since [some believe that there can be liquid metal hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_hydrogen#Liquid_metallic_hydrogen).

Comment: @Uwe I've adjusted the wording to be "Is here believed to be..."